# update Rails / ActiveRecord / SQL database dynamically

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a database full of stories, and each story belongs to a user.

I already have a user_id attribute for each story.

I recently added a user_name attribute to all my stories as well.

Now all of those user_name attributes are nil.

In the console, I can do `Story.first.user_name = Story.first.user.name` to set the user_name attribute to the first story's user.name value.

How can I iterate through all my stories in my Postgresql database and dynamically update each story's user_name value?

I want to use something like ActiveRecord's update_all method, but with a dynamic argument.

I tried in the Rails console:

`Story.update_all('user_name = Story.user.name')`

but that returned:

`SQL (36.2ms)  UPDATE "stories" SET user_name = Story.user.name
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user"
LINE 1: UPDATE "stories" SET user_name = Story.user.name
                                         ^
: UPDATE "stories" SET user_name = Story.user.name
    from (irb):14`

[image: SQL-error-missing-FROM-clause]

Not sure how to use the FROM in raw SQL, or how to write the correct command in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Can you please make clear the logic you want to use to update the data? Also why do you need a field in the story if you already have that data in the user model?  Is there a reason you want to duplicate data in the DB ?

Comment: In the database, I want to iterate over each story, and update its user_name attribute. Each story belongs to a user, so I want to set each user_name to each story's user.name value.

Comment: But why duplicate this data if you already have a user that has a name? Also, when should this data migration happen? It sounds like you just need to write a data migration.

Comment: I no longer want to show all the user data for each story, since that data includes email addresses and other info that I don't need or want in the API endpoint. I just want each story to have a user_name attribute.

Comment: My question is: how can I use update_all to update attributes dynamically?

Comment: You can't do this with `update_all`

Comment: @EthanRyan, can you elaborate in "dynamically". Anyways, this is invalid syntax: `update_all('user_name = Story.user.name')`, try `update_all(user_name: Story.user.name)`, where Story.user.name is evaluated as isn't within quotes.

Comment: `Story.user` implies `user` is a class method.. this can't be right can it? @SebastianPalma wouldn't this update all the records to a single `user_name` ?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you clarify the relations between stories and users... are the both HABTM ?

Comment: stories belong to users, and users have many stories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to iterate over all records in the stories table:

```
Story.find_each {|story| story.update(user_name: story.user.name)}
```

If your goal is not to touch timestamps or validations as with `update_all` you can do

```
Story.find_each {|story| story.update_column(:user_name, story.user.name)}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I was hoping to use update_all because it doesn't update the updated_at timestamp field, according to the first comment here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: There is a way to do this with sql but not quite so simple. But why do you care about the timestamp? Is this a one off run? It is more recommended to to this in a migration if this is in production data.

Comment: It is a one off run, but I'm sorting my stories by updated_at in a table on the frontend, so didn't want to update their timestamps. But if there isn't an easy want to update the user_name attribute without also updating the updated_at value, I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: There is a way, but that is a separate question.

Comment: Is that a separate question? My question is: How can I iterate through all my stories in my Postgresql database and dynamically update each story's user_name value?

I want to use something like ActiveRecord's update_all method, but with a dynamic argument.

Comment: Dynamic does not automatically imply "don't touch timestamps" and we already determined you can't really use `update_all` for this purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182232/discussion-between-ethan-ryan-and-lacostenycoder).